Conditions on LR in Gradient Descent
In Introductory Lectures in Convex Optimization by Yurii Nesterov, Section 1.2.3 shows that gradient descent is guaranteed to converge if the step size is chosen either with a fixed step size or chosen by the Goldstein-Armijo rule.
Do you know if there exists conditions on a variable step size (upper/lower bounds?) which guarantees the convergence of gradient descent? (The conditions need not guarantee convergence to a local minimum, just to a stationary point). Thank you!
